# Database error on codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`warehouse_inventory_system`.`inventory_products`, CONSTRAINT `fk_category` FOREIGN KEY (`Category_Id`) REFERENCES `category` (`Category_Id`))
>   INSERT INTO `inventory_products` (`Product_Name`, `Category_Id`, `Brand_Name`, `Unit_Price`, `Date_of_Entry`, `Quantity`) VALUES (0, 0, '1', '120', '2016-03-31', '12')

The code run is

```
<?php
 $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM category');

 foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
     echo '<option value="'. $row->Category_Id. '">'. $row->Category_Name. '</option>';

  }
?>

Insert code is:
function create(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Unit_Price','Unit_Price','trim|xss_clean|numeric|is_natural_no_zero|min_length[2]');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Quantity','Quantity','trim|xss_clean|numeric|is_natural_no_zero');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }

        else
        {
            $data = array(
            'Product_Name' => $this->input->post('Product_Name'),
            'Category_Id' => $this->input->post('Category_Id'),
            'Brand_Name' => $this->input->post('Brand_Name'),
            'Unit_Price' => $this->input->post('Unit_Price'),
            'Date_of_Entry' => $this->input->post('Date_of_Entry'),
            'Quantity' => $this->input->post('Quantity')
            );

            $this->Admin_model->add_items($data);

            $this->index();

        }
    }
Admin_model
function add_items($data){
    $this->db->insert('inventory_products', $data);
    return;
}
```

Comment: you have foreign key reference on that table you not inserting the value. Hence it's throwing error `0` is not a valid value

Comment: Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a new record to `inventory_products` table with `category_id` equals 0 and because `inventory_products` refers to `category` table and there is no record in `category` table with category_id = 0, it throws a foreign key constraint fails error.

Check your `<input>` and `<select>` and make sure their `name` attributes matched the one you read in PHP code. For example: there must be an `<select>` tag with name `Category_Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try altering `'Category_Id' => $this->input->post('Category_Id')` to a defined value instead of a `$_POST` value and see if the error persists. If no error occurs it can be traced to the `$this->input->post('Category_Id')` not being properly set (or being set to `0` in this case), resulting in SQL reporting that this required key is not being supplied.